# Scroll bar in InteractiveViewer Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollbar

How can I make scroll bar in InteractiveViewer that can controll moving in InteractiveViewer?
I want to put one scroll bar horizontally and one vertically and use these two bars to control the screen movement of the InteractiveViewer
I've been looking at a lot of ways, but I haven't found anything about InteractiveViewer